# Cellular telephone calls from iPad

Tags: ipad

I have an iPad air.
It displays PK UFONE only but I want to send and receive text messages from SIM and want to call over local network using cellular SIM NETWORK. So, please guide me what should I do? How I can do a package from a SIM to use internet however or does not allow to call any number from iPad?

Answer (score 4):

If you have an iPhone too, and both your iPad and iPhone are running iOS 8, then you can make phone calls from your iPad, which then uses your iPhone to make call from.

> **Phone calls**
>
> With Continuity, you can make and receive cellular phone calls from your iPad, iPod touch, or Mac when your iPhone is on the same Wi-Fi network.
>
> To make and receive phone calls, here's what you need:
>
> 1. Sign in to the same iCloud account on all your devices, including your Mac.
> 2. Your iPhone and your iPad or iPod touch need to use iOS 8 or later. Your Mac needs to use OS X Yosemite.
> 3. All devices must be on the same Wi-Fi network.
> 4. All devices must be signed in to FaceTime using the same iCloud account. This means any device that shares your Apple ID will get your phone calls. Look below for instructions on how to turn off iPhone cellular calls.
> 5. Wi-Fi Calling needs to be off. Go to Settings > Phone. If you see Wi-Fi Calling, turn it off.

http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT6337

Answer (score 2):

An iPad is not a telephone.

It can be done with 3rd party solutions like [Skype](http://www.skype.com) or [Viber](http://www.viber.com), but not natively.

By default it is capable of data over cellular, but not standard voice calls.

Comment: That gets blurred with ios 8 tho... see @Rene Larson's answer...

Comment: True, but the OP didn't mention any other Apple devices, so I went for the one-box answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

iPad is not meant for making calls. The usage of sim card on iPad is for internet usage through 3G or LTE. That is the only reason for the existence of a cellular version of the iPad.

If you wanted to make calls from a tablet, you should've gone in the Android route or just bought an iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

I see no problem here.... calls are calls whether VoIP or cellular. If you want to make calls with your iPad there are many apps out there to let you call any landline or mobile. Skype and Hangouts are 2 examples. It's a bit like asking if your car will run with Michelin or Pirelli tyres..... and if you are so insistent on making that cellular call. There is a pretty good device available for this.... a cellphone.